# NoSuchElementException error, even when app icon is clicked

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium-android

I am automating an Android app for my company, and there is an extremely weird error that I am encountering.

Here is the script that I am initiating

```py
import exceptiongroup
from appium import webdriver
from appium.webdriver.common.appiumby import AppiumBy
import subprocess
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions import interaction
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.action_builder import ActionBuilder
from selenium.webdriver.common.actions.pointer_input import PointerInput
from selenium.webdriver.support import wait
import time

init_android_emulator = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Pixel_6_API_30.bat"
subprocess.Popen(init_android_emulator)
time.sleep(60)
emulator_tasks = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Android_emulator_tasks.bat"
subprocess.Popen(emulator_tasks)

caps = {}
caps["platformName"] = "Android"
caps["appium:automationName"] = "UIAutomator2"
caps["appium:platformVersion"] = "11.0"
caps["appium:app"] = "C:/Users/DELL/SaralApp.apk"
caps["appium:deviceName"] = "Pixel 6 API 30"
caps["appium:noReset"] = True
caps["appium:ensureWebviewsHavePages"] = True
caps["appium:nativeWebScreenshot"] = True
caps["appium:newCommandTimeout"] = 3600
caps["appium:connectHardwareKeyboard"] = True

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723", caps)
time.sleep(10)
def open_app():
    saral_app_icon = driver.find_element(AppiumBy.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, "Saral")
    if saral_app_icon.is_displayed():
        print("App is visible")
        saral_app_icon.click()
    else:
        print("App not visible")


open_app()
emulator_kill = "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/Android_emulator_kill_tasks.bat"
subprocess.Popen(emulator_kill)
```

and this is the error that I am getting

```
NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrEls (C:\Users\DELL.appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-driver\node_modules\appium-android-driver\lib\commands\find.js:75:11) at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElOrElsWithProcessing (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:60:12) at AndroidUiautomator2Driver.findElement (C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules@appium\base-driver\lib\basedriver\commands\find.ts:75:12)
```

and this basically appears after the app is clicked and opened.

I tried downloading the app directly while initiating the test case and did not help. I also tried bring the app to the homescreen did not help. I also tried adding multiple wait and sleep statements, it did not help.